# How to join two queries with count?

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables in database:

1. Table 1: violation

```
| violation_id  | violation_name |
|:-------------:|:--------------:|
|1              | No Parking     |
|2              | Speed Contest  |
|3              | No Helmet      |
```

2. Table 2: violators

```
| violator_id   | violation_id   |
|:-------------:|:--------------:|
|1              |1               |
|2              |1               |
|3              |3               |
```

3. Table 2: previous_violator

```
| prev_violator_id| violation_id   |
|:---------------:|:--------------:|
|1                |1               |
|2                |2               |
|3                |2               |
```

This view that I want:

```
| violation_name  | Total |
|:-------------:|:--------------:|
|No Parking     | 3              |
|Speed Contest  | 2              |
|No Helmet      | 1              |
```

I perform this code that joins the violator table and violation:

```
SELECT *,count(violators.violation_id) as vid 
FROM violators 
    LEFT JOIN violation ON violation.violation_id = violators.violation_id 
    LEFT JOIN previous_violator ON previous_violator.violator_id = violators.violator_id 
WHERE date_apphrehend BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' 
GROUP BY violators.violation_id
```

My problem is, I want to join the previous violator table that count to the total based on the violation_name.

Comment: Maybe you want to use count(distinct violation.violation_name) and grouping by violators.violator_id ? Please clarify your question.

Comment: can you provide an expected output for clarity?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can first union all to get them into a single result and then count(*) it. Finally join with Violation to get names. ie:

```
select violation_name, count(*) as cnt
    from (select violation_id from Violators
          union all
          select violation_id from previous_Violators) tmp
    inner join Violation on tmp.violation_id = Violation.violation_id 
    group by Violation.violation_id, violation_name;
```

Sample [DBFiddle demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=47b5c8c6df4321f0d1dfb1f774dc4e54)

PS: Sample is in postgreSQL but it would be the same for most backends. You didn't tag your backend.